# JavaScript Regex Help!

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a @ tags within this string:

```
 @sam @gt @channel:sam dfgfdh sam@sam
```

Now in regex testers this works `@[\S]+` (with settings on JS testing) to pick out all strings starting with @ so in them I get:

```
@sam @gt @channel:sam @sam
```

But then in browsers using this code:

```
function detect_extractStatusUsers(status){
var e = new RegExp('@[\S]+', 'i');
m = e.exec(status);
var s= "";

if (m != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        s = s + m[i] + "\n";
    }
    alert(s);
}

return true;
}
```

I can only get one single match of `@` (if I'm lucky, normally no match).

I must be missing something here and my eyes have just been looking at this for too long to see what it is.

Can anyone see what's wrong in this function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to:

- use the global search `g` setting
- escape your \
- use `match` instead of `exec`

  `var e = new RegExp('@[\\S]+', 'gi');`

  `m = status.match(e);`

Comment: Hmm it don't work, it still only picks out @s from @sam calling that exact function (with the added g flag) like: `detect_extractStatusUsers("@sam");`

Comment: I updated my answer addressing other issues in your functionality.

Comment: Woo cheers, I knew it was something simple. Full points given :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `exec` repeatedly, until it returns `null`.  Each time it will return a `match` object, containing all the captures for that match.

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your function the way I would have written it:

```
function detect_extractStatusUsers(status){
    var rx = /(@[\S]+)/gi,
        match,
        tags = [];
    while (match = e.exec(status)) {
        tags.push(match[1]);
    }
    if (tags.length > 0) {
        alert(tags.join('\n'));
    }
}
```